# Create new dataframe from repeated exposure and participants and only add new data

Tags: r, dplyr, data-munging

Happy Tuesday.

I am currently collecting survey data.  The surveys sometimes ask the same questions and other times do not.  Why? Because there is 700+ questions and asking a participant to answer all of these (without payment) is not very realistic.  So we are giving surveys of subsets of the items.  Herein lies the problem.  Some participants will take the survey more than one time (which is totally okay); however, I do not want to document their response when they answers the same question for the second (or third, fourth etc) time.  However, when they respond to new questions I want to store that data.  My thoughts on how to do this are to create a growing master data set with all the participants information, then when new data comes in query as to if the participant has responded to the surveys before and then only add their new information to the data file to be analyzed.  Then, repeat this process when the next batch of survey results come in.  In my head, after the dataframe to be analyzed has been updated, it could then be used to query any new data coming in.

So let me try and demonstrate the workflow to help guide a discussion, or even help someone identify a solution.

*note2: Dplyr may also be a relevant packing.  Again, tagging, but if it is not relevant I can remove.

```
library(dplyr)
survey1 = structure(list(ip = c(111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 
                      999, 1110), gender = c("Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
                                             "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"), age = c(23, 
                                                                                                              26, 23, 60, 30, 35, 27, 61, 49, 33), education = c(16, 18, 4, 
                                                                                                                                                                 18, 16, 19, 19, 14, 22, 16), race = c("White", "White", "Asian", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White"
                                                                                                                                                                 ), Q4 = c("Dresser", "dresser", "drawers", "Dresser", "Dresser", 
                                                                                                                                                                           "Dresser", "Dresser", "dresser", "dresser", "dresser"), Q4a = c("Dresser", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "dresser", "drawers", "Dresser", "Dresser", "Dresser", "Dresser", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "dresser", "dresser", "dresser"), Q417 = c("Crib", "crib", "crib", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "Baby crib", "Crib", "Crib", "Crib", "crib", "crib", "crib"), 
               Q417a = c("Crib", "crib", "crib", "Baby crib", "Crib", "Crib", 
                         "Crib", "crib", "crib", "crib"), Q536 = c("Couch", "couch", 
                                                                   "couch", "Couch or sofa", "Couch", "Couch", "Leather couch", 
                                                                   "sofa", "couch", "sofa"), Q536a = c("Sofa", "couch", "couch", 
                                                                                                       "Couch or sofa", "Couch", "Couch", "Couch", "sofa", "couch", 
                                                                                                       "sofe"), Q491 = c("Roof", "roof", "house", "Roof", "Roof", 
                                                                                                                         "Roof", "Roof", "roof", "roof", "roof"), Q491a = c("Roof tile", 
                                                                                                                                                                            "roof", "roof", "Roof", "Roof", "Roof", "Roof", "rooof", 
                                                                                                                                                                            "roof", "roof"), Q452 = c("Rug", "rug", "rug", "Oriental carpet", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      "Rug", "Rug", "Rug", "rug", "rug", "rug"), Q452a = c("Rug", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "rug", "rug", "Carpet", "Rug", "Rug", "Rug", "carpet", "rug", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "rug")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "data.frame"))#ready in survey 2
survey2= structure(list(ip = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), gender = c("Female", 
                                                                          "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
                                                                          "Male", "Male"), age = c(23, 26, 23, 60, 30, 35, 27, 61, 49, 
                                                                                                   33), education = c(16, 18, 4, 18, 16, 19, 19, 14, 22, 16), race = c("White", 
                                                                                                                                                                       "White", "Asian", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
                                                                                                                                                                       "White", "White"), Q4 = c("dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog"), Q4a = c("cat", "cat", "cat", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat"), Q417 = c("van", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "van", "van", "van", "van", "van", "van", "van", "van", "van"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ), Q417a = c("chocolate", "chocolate", "chocolate", "chocolate", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "chocolate", "chocolate", "chocolate", "chocolate", "chocolate", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "chocolate"), Q536 = c("candy", "candy", "candy", "candy", "candy", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "candy", "candy", "candy", "candy", "candy"), Q536a = c("pizza", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "pizza", "pizza", "pizza", "pizza", "pizza", "pizza", "pizza", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "pizza", "pizza"), Q491 = c("ocotpus", "ocotpus", "ocotpus", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "ocotpus", "ocotpus", "ocotpus", "ocotpus", "ocotpus", "ocotpus", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "ocotpus"), Q491a = c("panther", "panther", "panther", "panther", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "panther", "panther", "panther", "panther", "panther", "panther"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ), Q452 = c("checkers", "checkers", "checkers", "checkers", "checkers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "checkers", "checkers", "checkers", "checkers", "checkers"), 
                        Q452a = c("computer", "computer", "computer", "computer", 
                                  "computer", "computer", "computer", "computer", "computer", 
                                  "computer")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                  ), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
                                    ip = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
                                    )), gender = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                             "collector")), age = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                              "collector")), education = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), race = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "collector")), Q4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "collector")), Q4a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "collector")), Q417 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "collector")), Q417a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "collector")), Q536 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "collector")), Q536a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "collector")), Q491 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "collector")), Q491a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "collector")), Q452 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "collector")), Q452a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

As can be seen in the data thus far, no participants that took survey1 also took survey2.  We know this from the IP (address) difference.  So adding them together is no sweat.

```
masterData = rbind(survey1, survey2)
str(masterdata) #reveals tibble [20 x 15]
```

Now lets say we get a new survey in, here survey 3 has all the same participants as survey 1. However, 4 of the questions overlap, but we get new data from these participants for 5 new questions.  I would like to create a new dataframe and add only the new questions for these participants.  Example:

```
survey3 =structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), ip = c(111, 
222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, 1110), gender = c("Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male"), age = c(23, 26, 23, 60, 30, 35, 27, 61, 49, 
33), education = c(16, 18, 4, 18, 16, 19, 19, 14, 22, 16), race = c("White", 
"White", "Asian", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
"White", "White"), Q4 = c("Dresser", "dresser", "drawers", "Dresser", 
"Dresser", "Dresser", "Dresser", "dresser", "dresser", "dresser"
), Q4a = c("Dresser", "dresser", "drawers", "Dresser", "Dresser", 
"Dresser", "Dresser", "dresser", "dresser", "dresser"), Q417 = c("Crib", 
"crib", "crib", "Baby crib", "Crib", "Crib", "Crib", "crib", 
"crib", "crib"), Q417a = c("Crib", "crib", "crib", "Baby crib", 
"Crib", "Crib", "Crib", "crib", "crib", "crib"), Q15 = c("waffle", 
"waffle", "waffle", "waffle", "waffle", "waffle", "waffle", "waffle", 
"waffle", "waffle"), Q16 = c("egg", "egg", "egg", "egg", "egg", 
"egg", "egg", "egg", "egg", "egg"), Q17 = c("bacon", "bacon", 
"bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", 
"bacon"), Q18 = c("pancake", "pancake", "pancake", "pancake", 
"pancake", "pancake", "pancake", "pancake", "pancake", "pancake"
), Q19 = c("smoothie", "smoothie", "smoothie", "smoothie", "smoothie", 
"smoothie", "smoothie", "smoothie", "smoothie", "smoothie")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), ip = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), gender = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), age = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), education = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), race = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q4a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q417 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q417a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q15 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q16 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q17 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q18 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q19 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

The desired output of this merge would look something like this:

```
desiredoutput = structure(list(ip = c(111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 
999, 1110, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), gender = c("Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"), age = c(23, 26, 
23, 60, 30, 35, 27, 61, 49, 33, 23, 26, 23, 60, 30, 35, 27, 61, 
49, 33), education = c(16, 18, 4, 18, 16, 19, 19, 14, 22, 16, 
16, 18, 4, 18, 16, 19, 19, 14, 22, 16), race = c("White", "White", 
"Asian", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
"White", "White", "White", "Asian", "White", "White", "White", 
"White", "White", "White", "White"), Q4 = c("Dresser", "dresser", 
"drawers", "Dresser", "Dresser", "Dresser", "Dresser", "dresser", 
"dresser", "dresser", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", 
"dog", "dog", "dog", "dog"), Q4a = c("Dresser", "dresser", "drawers", 
"Dresser", "Dresser", "Dresser", "Dresser", "dresser", "dresser", 
"dresser", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", 
"cat", "cat"), Q417 = c("Crib", "crib", "crib", "Baby crib", 
"Crib", "Crib", "Crib", "crib", "crib", "crib", "van", "van", 
"van", "van", "van", "van", "van", "van", "van", "van"), Q417a = c("Crib", 
"crib", "crib", "Baby crib", "Crib", "Crib", "Crib", "crib", 
"crib", "crib", "chocolate", "chocolate", "chocolate", "chocolate", 
"chocolate", "chocolate", "chocolate", "chocolate", "chocolate", 
"chocolate"), Q536 = c("Couch", "couch", "couch", "Couch or sofa", 
"Couch", "Couch", "Leather couch", "sofa", "couch", "sofa", "candy", 
"candy", "candy", "candy", "candy", "candy", "candy", "candy", 
"candy", "candy"), Q536a = c("Sofa", "couch", "couch", "Couch or sofa", 
"Couch", "Couch", "Couch", "sofa", "couch", "sofe", "pizza", 
"pizza", "pizza", "pizza", "pizza", "pizza", "pizza", "pizza", 
"pizza", "pizza"), Q491 = c("Roof", "roof", "house", "Roof", 
"Roof", "Roof", "Roof", "roof", "roof", "roof", "ocotpus", "ocotpus", 
"ocotpus", "ocotpus", "ocotpus", "ocotpus", "ocotpus", "ocotpus", 
"ocotpus", "ocotpus"), Q491a = c("Roof tile", "roof", "roof", 
"Roof", "Roof", "Roof", "Roof", "rooof", "roof", "roof", "panther", 
"panther", "panther", "panther", "panther", "panther", "panther", 
"panther", "panther", "panther"), Q452 = c("Rug", "rug", "rug", 
"Oriental carpet", "Rug", "Rug", "Rug", "rug", "rug", "rug", 
"checkers", "checkers", "checkers", "checkers", "checkers", "checkers", 
"checkers", "checkers", "checkers", "checkers"), Q452a = c("Rug", 
"rug", "rug", "Carpet", "Rug", "Rug", "Rug", "carpet", "rug", 
"rug", "computer", "computer", "computer", "computer", "computer", 
"computer", "computer", "computer", "computer", "computer"), 
    Q15 = c("waffle", "waffle", "waffle", "waffle", "waffle", 
    "waffle", "waffle", "waffle", "waffle", "waffle", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q16 = c("egg", "egg", "egg", 
    "egg", "egg", "egg", "egg", "egg", "egg", "egg", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q17 = c("bacon", "bacon", 
    "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", 
    "bacon", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q18 = c("pancake", 
    "pancake", "pancake", "pancake", "pancake", "pancake", "pancake", 
    "pancake", "pancake", "pancake", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Q19 = c("smoothie", "smoothie", "smoothie", 
    "smoothie", "smoothie", "smoothie", "smoothie", "smoothie", 
    "smoothie", "smoothie", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    ip = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), gender = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), age = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), education = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), race = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q4a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q417 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q417a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q536 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q536a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q491 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q491a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q452 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q452a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q15 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q16 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q17 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q18 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Q19 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

One thing I am trying to be conscious of is to *hopefully* make this an iterative process as new surveys come in (eg. surver4 - survery1000)

Any help or ideas would be appreciated here as I am not clear as to how to attack this problem.

Comment: take a look at this. You'll get answers faster https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @AlbersonMiranda The data is reproducible and to my knowledge the problem is outlined pretty well.  I am familiar with this page and would find your comment far more helpful if you explicitly stated what was not helpful about the post.

Comment: easy, dude. To clarify, a good reprex is also *minimal*. TL;DR

Comment: Appreciate the clarification.  Your comment was simply hard to swallow after taking a fair amount of time to make the code reproducible etc. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to keep data in long format i.e every row has answer for one question. Also turn the new survey data in long format as well.

Let's assume `masterData` already has `survey1` and `survey2` and now you are trying to add `survey3` in it. You can combine `survey3` in `master_data` and then keep only unique rows for each participant and each question. Assuming every participant is uniquely identified by it's `ip`, `age`, `education` and `race` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

masterData <- masterData %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Q'))
new_survey <- survey3 %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Q'))

get_new_master <- function(masterData, new_data) {
  bind_rows(masterData, new_data) %>%
   distinct(ip, gender, age, education, race, name, .keep_all = TRUE)
}
```

Here column `name` is the question number. You can then call `get_new_master` as :

```
masterData <- get_new_master(masterData, new_survey)
```

Now `masterData` has complete data, when another survey comes in we can follow the same process.

```
new_survey <- survey4 %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Q'))
masterData <- get_new_master(masterData, new_survey)
```